# Grouping objects in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object, vbscript

I am trying to group two object into one list to be iterated in one 'for each' loop. Is it even possible in VBA/VBscript?

For example I would like to delete all files **and** folders from a specific location basing on last mod. date and I don't want to create two loops.

```
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set oFileList = oFolder.Files
Set oFolderList = oFolder.SubFolders
Set oFullList = oFileList + oFolderList (???)

For Each oFile In oFullList 
    lastModDate = oFile.DateLastModified
    If (lastModDate < PurgeDate) Then
        oFile.Delete True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: To merge the lists you will need to loop.

Comment: @xLokos VBA or VBScript which is it?

Comment: @Lankymart In this particular case I don't think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible with `FileSystemObject` methods alone. Even if you created a single array or ArrayList from the elements of `oFolder.Files` and `oFolder.SubFolders` you'd need two individual loops to do so.

You could use the `Shell.Application` object for enumerating folder content, but the resulting objects don't have a delete method, so you'd still need `FileSystemObject` objects and methods for deleting the files/folders:

```
path = "C:\some\folder"

Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each it In app.NameSpace(path).Items
    If it.IsFolder Then
        fso.GetFolder(it.Path).Delete
    Else
        fso.GetFile(it.Path).Delete
    End If
Next
```

However, I fail to see a significant advantage of this approach over using just `FileSystemObject` methods and looping twice. If you're concerned about duplicating code just wrap the loop in a procedure and call that procedure for both subfolders and files.

```
path = "C:\some\folder"

Sub DeleteItems(list)
    For Each it In list
        it.Delete
    Next
End Sub

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(path)

DeleteItems oFolder.Files
DeleteItems oFolder.SubFolders
```